# Implementing a ConstraintValidation for an enum

Tags: java, enums, constraints, hibernate-validator

I am looking to go from using POJOs to enums. One thing that's in my way is hibernate validation. I have been looking up how to apply validations to enum classes, but at most I am finding information on how to validate an enum property of a POJO, which is not what I want.

An example of the enum class I want to validate is;

```
EMAIL("email","v1",STRING),
FIRST_NAME("firstName","v1",STRING),
LAST_NAME("lastName","v1",STRING),
AGE("age","v1",INTEGER)
```

I haven't seen of or heard of using annotations on enums, but is there a way to write a custom validator that will check each enum and make sure its not null and is of the correct type?

The enums will not be saved to the db, they will be parsed and transferred to another service that will then save it to the db. I would parse first then validate but the way the code is written, this can't be done. I want to validate that the enums are meeting the db constraints

Comment: You don't want to put `enum`s in your database as their own table. They should be constant and in your code.

Comment: No, all it is doing is checking the validations and once that's clear it will be parsed and sent to another stream. Only issue is that the validation has to come before the parsing